# Equation of a plane given one point and two planes

Tags: analytic-geometry

I've done a question similar to this, however this one has no complete equations i can solve for.

> Determine the equation of the plane that passes through $(1,3,8)$ and is perpendicular to the line of intersection of the planes $3x-2z+1=0$ and $4x+3y+7=0$.

I know to take the cross product of the two normals to get my new direction vector, but im stuck at that point.

Comment: That cross-product is the normal of the plane, and you know a point that the plane contains, right? Now use your standard formula for a plane.

Comment: wouldn't i have to find a point on this new planes itself? or two parameters?

Comment: Nope. The normal vector to the plane and a point in that plane are sufficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane

Comment: BTW, in the title, it should say "plane", not "line".

Comment: So use the dot product to calculate my new normal, I have a point, and put it all together in vector form. Awesome thanks!